# App-to-Phone call Nexmo

Tags: php, cordova, ionic-framework, vonage

I am new to Nexmo and I am trying to set up an App-to-Phone call. A voice call is initiated by the user of a mobile Ionic/Cordova app via the internet and a phone rings on the PSTN. The callee answers and both parties can speak and listen.

Now I have set up the server and I am able to get the phone on the PSTN to be called, I can answer it and I can use NCCO to speak a text to the callee.

I can't however, figure out how to handle Nexmo on the callers client side. How do I set up the connection between the app and the PSTN? How is the voice exchange sent and received via Nexmo? I can only find examples which use Text-to-Speech in the docs and the [npm nexmo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexmo) package.

My server has this code from the Nexmo [docs](https://docs.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/calls):

```
 <?php

include 'application_generate_jwt.php';

//Connection information
$base_url = 'https://api.nexmo.com' ;
$version = '/v1';
$action = '/calls';

//User and application information
$application_id = "id-for-your-voice-application";

//Mint your JWT
$keyfile="application_secret_key.txt";

$jwt = generate_jwt($application_id, $keyfile);

//Add the JWT to the request headers
$headers =  array('Content-Type: application/json', "Authorization: Bearer " . $jwt ) ;

//Change the to parameter to the number you want to call
$payload = '{
    "to":[{
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "441632960961"
    }],
    "from": {
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "441632960960"
    },
    "answer_url": ["https://nexmo-community.github.io/ncco-examples/first_call_talk.json"]
}';

//Create the request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url . $version . $action);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

If more information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: The present Nexmo Voice API is build to work with server-side technologies and not client-side technologies. So you can't control the calls on the client via a client-side app.

Comment: Hi, I understand that the call flow is handled server side. But is it at all possible to initiate a telephone call inside a mobile app via the internet (through my server) to a number on the PSTN using the Nexmo Voice API? Or would I need to use SIP?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do this with Nexmo, it really depends if you know the phone number of the device with the app on it.

If so then you can make an outbound call to each phone number from nexmo and put them both into a simple conference (known as a conversation in NCCO speak)
https://docs.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/ncco-reference#conversation
You just need to ensure that the name of the conversation is unique to that call.

The other way to do it would be via proxy calling so the app launches a 'tel:' url which contains a nexmo phone number which the client calls into and that then executes an NCCO that connects the call on to the destination number.

It depends on what your use case is as to which model would work best, also in option 1 you will bear the cost of 2 calls (one to each phone) in option 2 you will have one call cost and the user of the app with have the other.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! Is there any Nexmo documentation on the second option, the proxy call? We don't know the phone number from the mobile app user, so the second option fits our use case best.

Comment: Could you confirm this for me: In the second option the app launches the 'tel' url containing the Nexmo number, the mobile phone switches from my mobile app to the 'Phone' app from which regular calls are made, and the user calls Nexmo from there. The user would get charged by his provider for calling the Nexmo number because he is calling via the PSTN and not via an internet connection.